# Ubuntu suddenly does not load anymore

Tags: installation, 9.10

For the first time EVER - Ubuntu will not load. It was working fine this morning, but since it will not work. I cannot get it past the initial security area where it asks for a password, but even then - it will not load it enough so that the password can be entered. I am not tech savvy, but I'd like to keep the previous files, and links - then reinstall Ubuntu back on the system. Ideally I'd like to wipe it clean but only have the Ubuntu 9.10 Desktop Edition Single Disc.

Can anyone help with a walk through?

Answer (score 2):

You should check if you can boot your PC with a Live-CD. If not, the Hardware is seriously broken.
If you can, you can access your files, backup them and reinstall the system.
However I doubt that a new install would work for long, as an Ubuntu installation hardly just breaks without faulty Hardware or the user manipulating the system in a wrong way.

Comment: I did a reinstall side by side apparently the computer also has 10.4 on there. I may decide to update the version I am using since it's online. I am having trouble though that the mouse is not being completely responsive. I can't double click with the mouse on things, I have to highlight with the mouse, and then hit the enter button to make the function I want work. Anyone by chance know what I did wrong on the install or can it be corrected without another installation?